# DRF ModelSerializers dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm starting in DRF and I'm trying to make a serializer for my login system with a ModelSerializer passing certain Fields or with all fields but I always get the same error using ModelSerializer, I managed to solve it without using the ModelSerializer but I want to do it with this one but I can't find any solution :(

ModelSerializer

```
class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'phone_number',
        ]
```

View

```
class UserRegisterAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        data = {'user_data': UserModelSerializer(user).data}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

UserRegisterSeriliazer

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(min_length = 8, max_length=25, validators = [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8,  max_length=25)
    password_confirmation = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=24)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=25)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=25)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=25, validators = [UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex = r'\+?1?\d{8,10}$',
        message = 'Please enter a valid phone number'
    )
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(validators=[phone_regex])
```

Traceback

```
 Exception has occurred: ValueError
 dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
 File "D:\restapi\users\views\users.py", line 28, in post
 data = {'user_data': UserModelSerializer(user).data}
 ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is 
 required
```

I tried using a normal serializer and it solved it but I don't understand why with a modelserializer it doesn't work, besides I want to apply with modelserializer for good practices.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback of the error?

Comment: yes of course, sorry for replying so late I didn't get the notification and I just came in and saw your comment, here is the traceback: 

Exception has occurred: ValueError
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
  File "D:\restapi\users\views\users.py", line 16, in post
    'user': UserModelSerializer(user).data,
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required